# Unexpected token ' { '. Import call expects exactly one argument. React Native

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native

В приложении React Native возникает такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

App.js

```
import {TailwindProvider} from "tailwindcss-react-native";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {store} from "./store";
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import CreateTodoScreen from "./screens/СreateTodoScreen";

export default function App() {

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    return (
        <TailwindProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        <Stack.Screen name="Мои задачи" component={HomeScreen}/>
                        <Stack.Screen name="Создать задачу" component={CreateTodoScreen}/>
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        </TailwindProvider>

    );
}
```

Comment: Что у вас в `store`? Похоже ругается на `import {store} from "./store";`

Comment: import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import todoReducer from './slices/todoSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        todos:todoReducer,
    },
})

Comment: https://thecode.media/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import-call-expects-exactly-one-argument/

Comment: Ну это вроде не касается моего вопроса